# Can I include a web link in my application materials?

Tags: resume, websites

When I prepare my application materials using LaTeX and finally get a PDF file, I am able to insert a hyperlink so that people can click on that word to see my webpage, my online code repository, etc.

My question is that, is it a good practice or should it be avoided? If it should be avoided, what should I do instead? I'm concerned the hiring manager may be reluctant to click unknown links.

Comment: [Related question to format of links](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/is-it-good-idea-to-shorten-urls-in-a-cv/1085#1085)

Comment: On my resume, under my name and address I put the link to my website so that if they want to go to my website they can. My website contains projects I have worked on and I feel like it should be a part of my resume.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used to do the exact same thing until I read that most hiring managers and recruiters actually print your resume off making your link un-clickable.  Apparently, this is a big source of annoyance for hiring managers.  Go figure.

If you are going to put a link in your resume, make sure it is the URL itself so the person viewing your printed resume can type it into their computer if they are interested.

This sounds a little antiquated I know, but that's how things are done today.  I would wager that things are trending more towards hiring managers viewing digital resumes (even in the physical interview via tablets, etc.)  However, the majority of them will still print your resume off, and you should be prepared for that.

If you want some additional help getting started Manager Tools has a fantastic [Resume Workbook](http://manager-tools.com/resume-workbook) which helped me out immensely.  My resume was a horrible mess before I updated it using their advice.

Comment: Link to 'Resume Workbook' says Access Denied.

Answer (score 2):

Enter the URL in full rather than including a link. As Robert says, most CVs are printed so the link is lost. Many CVs are also skimmed so the link can be missed.

When relevant and where space allows, I would recommend including links to examples of your work, endorsements from others, certifications and so on. Not everyone reading the CV will follow it but backing up your claimed achievements is never a bad thing.