# Is it right to ask work related questions on stackoverflow and network sites?

Tags: work-environment

1. Is it professionally acceptable to ask questions related to work on
   stackoverflow and stackexchange network of websites ?
2. Do we cite the source of answer even if not asked if someone asks at
   work ?
3. For this reason is it better to have a nickname as stackexchange
   profile name ?

Comment: Not sure as it stands here if it fit for workplace or meta. But here are some elements : 1-) SO and SE sites are for professional and enthusiast so yes it is acceptable, you may need to anonymise some elements. FOr SO don't forget to provide an MVCE. 2 : it is always better to quote a reference. 3 For anything like SO questions, having a real name is not a problem, but when discussing trouble at the workplace, you really want a nickname.

Comment: @Walfrat your comment is an answer.  I'd upvote it.

Comment: I made it an answer, I think to stand as a question for the workplace instead off meta (and maybe more general, asking help on the net and not only SE) it might need some rephrasing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about how to use Stack Exchange, not how to navigate a professional workplace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I avoid telling others that I ask questions on Stack Overflow?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/97200/should-i-avoid-telling-others-that-i-ask-questions-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: Isn't that the whole reason why Jeff & Joel started SO? What exactly is your issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. SO and SE sites are for professional and enthusiast so yes it is acceptable, you may need to anonymise some elements. For SO don't forget to provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example (MVCE).
2. It is always better to quote a reference.
3. For anything like SO questions, having a real name is not a problem, but when discussing trouble at the workplace, you really want a nickname