# I am at the top 7% os stackoverflow, does it gives me an advantage if I disclose it at my cv

Tags: resume

Hello at stackoverflow I am at the top 7% of their users. Is that a somewhat good indication about how good/bad I am as a Software Engineer?

I mean if I apply to a [**Hellenic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellenic) Company as Software Engineer will be considered as a plus or as a minus if I disclose this information to my cv?

Comment: Have you considered that it might be suggested that you could be spending too much "work time" on stack overflow .... ?

Comment: @brhans some might think same about contributing to Open Source :-(

Comment: Related: [A decent stack-exchange score for resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/119745). Also, you're top 7% *this year*, and seemingly [top 19% overall](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31/4706711?sort=reputationchange#4706711).

Comment: I would say it's a plus, but I wouldn't point out your rank, just link to your profile

Comment: Duplicate on Meta SE: [At what point do you put your SO reputation in your resume?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58947)

Answer (score 13):

> Is that a somewhat good indication about how good/bad I am as a Software Engineer?

**No**.

It's an indication about how good/bad you are at asking coherent/intelligent questions and answering same (btw, congratulations).

As for whether it's a plus or minus, consider:

- Some people may be impressed.
- Some may be unimpressed / wonder why it's on your resume
- Some will not recognize the significance (or worse, not recognize StackExchange!)

Personally, I'd leave it off my resume but be prepared to discuss it during the interview.

Comment: Good answer.. particularly the last line!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, StackOverflow/StackExchange tries to give you the most optimistic/cheerful number they can.  So on Workplace Stackexchange, I'm top 4% *this quarter*; in stackoverflow, I'm top 6% *this year*.  It doesn't say top % *all time* for either, because that number would probably be something like top 93% all time (aka, not all that impressive.)  And it doesn't say my Workplace number is for *this year*, because that number wouldn't be as impressive as what it happens to be for *this quarter*.

So... take pride in it... but not *too* much  :-)