# is stackoverflow or github profile more important than any degree

Tags: degree

I have a question in mind for few months

> ***Is degree (university,college or certificate) really important?***

I'm doing projects of web development and no one ask for **Degree** or **GPA**

But i faced most of time that clients ask for github/stackoverflow profile

Comment: Why is this attracting downvotes?

Comment: @Mars Seems almost (if not quite) trollish.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Why? It's actually a very common question for those considering web-dev. It could be worded better and is likely a duplicate, but I see nothing trollish here

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill It's come up on Meta Stack Overflow a few times too (not by the OP). This may not match your personal experience in job hunting but it's not a troll question.

Comment: @Mars I think people are voting to express disagreement with the premise or because there isn't enough information to give a good answer (location, industry, etc). As far as duplicates go, I haven't seen one that asks about both SO and GitHub but there's one for just SO: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/145913/do-employers-care-about-stack-overflow-reputation

Comment: I don't know why down votes but i just asked this question that i noticed in environment of education institutions. All institutions produces servants

Comment: I have taken the liberty of rolling this question back. I think it posed a legitimate question in the beginning, but was edited to be too broad, off-topic, and in general just an unwarranted rant. If you have follow-up questions, please ask a new question. It is also suggested that you show effort in researching the topic and evidence to back up questionable claims.

Comment: @Mars — To be clear, I didn’t say I downvoted; was just offering a guess as to why some people might.

Comment: @ernestfriedman-hill No problem. Didn't assume you did and wouldn't hold it against you even if you did

Answer (score 6):

Different things will be more or less important to different hiring managers (or clients). Ultimately, this question isn't directly answerable. Some people hiring in some fields care very much about degrees. Some people making hiring decisions don't even know what Stack Overflow is. Others who do know won't really *care.* And so on.

That said, it's important to focus on your own, personal plan, and the good news is, you can follow a process to answer this question for yourself:

- Determine the type of work you want to do
- Find out what's important to decision makers controlling that type of work
- Make a plan to get those things or reach those achievements, if you haven't already done so

Comment: +1.  If you don't have a degree then what does "yes, it's important" get you?  Instead figure out what you need to do to get the jobs you want.

Comment: thanks helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

When job hunting, often some things are binary and somethings are qualitative.

You can filter out candidates easily based on if they have a degree or not.

You can *compare* candidates based on their github/experience.
You can also compare by GPA, but that's generally not very useful for someone who has been working for X years.

Note that often a degree is assumed and a requirement. It's not uncommon to get dropped later in the interview process when the other side realizes you don't have a (relevant) degree.

Another note would be if you ever wish to work internationally--here a degree is often a very concrete requirement for a visa.

Comment: yeah i understand but is degree define someone who he really?

Comment: can a piece of paper define someone abilities??

Comment: @FaizanSadiq A degree isn't a piece of paper, a degree is something meant to show that "this person completed what we believe to be all of the requirements to demonstrate knowledge in X field." I'm not saying I agree, I'm not saying it's actually that important--I'm just saying that it's generally treated as something binary (yes or no) and assumed that applicants in the field of CS have.