# Is Stackexchange reputation useful in a CV?

Tags: resume, job-search

I've heard the stories that putting SE reputation in the CV can make it look better. I wonder if it is true when it comes to applying for jobs. Is it appropriate to do so? If it is true, how much reputation says that I am good, and how much would suggest that I am a rookie?

Comment: voting to close, as this is entirely opinion based. - Personally no, I think it looks unprofessional and silly on a CV. - You could add under a hobby section, that you dedicate some of your free time to helping others in the community via an online forum.

Comment: @flexi This is not enrtirely opinion based. There could be an agreement on this in the job-seeking world that I don't know of. Several questions on Academia SE asking about exactly the same thing receive dozens of upvotes, and I am just re-asking it in a job-seeking setting.

Comment: Just search the Workplace Stack E. site, there is already some information. (Maybe sou also.ask.in other foeums as this is obviously biases, good luck!

Comment: Also note that the answers in the other threat are from 2012. S. Exchange has evolved and is now more known, so don't take the answers from 2012 too seriously.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I include information about my reputation on professionally-relevant Stack Exchange (or other Q&A) sites on my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/308/should-i-include-information-about-my-reputation-on-professionally-relevant-stac)

Comment: @guest FWIW there was yet another question covering that just about half year ago - [Do employers care about Stack Overflow reputation?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/145913/168)

Comment: @gnat: Great!So, OP please use this question from gnat instead.

Answer (score 5):

Reputation is basically meaningless. Questions that get ranked high in Google search results and/or have click-baity titles will attract more attention and thus get more upvotes. It says little about the quality of the answers or the qualifications of their authors. If you have created some content that you're proud of, 
you might consider including a link to your profile so that prospective employers can see it but you should also keep in mind that having an inordinate amount of SE content could make people suspect that you have a habit of spending too much company time on non-work-related activities.

On the other hand, it shows that you're a benevolent person who enjoys helping people, which of course would be a good thing. I guess it really comes down to the individual reviewing your resume and how they choose to look at it. Regardless, I highly doubt that just putting your reputation score without any context would be helpful.

Comment: I had one person who was helping edit my resume for a translation position at the company she worked at cut out my reference to being top 2% on French SE, so that's when I decided it had little professional value :) Of course, that's also a field where no one has a clue what this site is...